# Highcharts Pie chart not centered on container

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, highcharts, carousel

Good morning. I'm trying to display various charts on a bootstrap's carousel. The problem is when I change to the second item of the carousel it's not displayed centered on the div. When I open firebug on FF or developer tools on Chrome it gets centered. I tried to set the width of the div to `width:100%` and centered the content but didn't worked. Any idea for a workaround? Here's the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/L4Aj9/.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is general problem for creating chart when container is hidden - widht and height isn't calculated from jQuery, so default width and height is used. See [FAQ](http://docs.highcharts.com/#faq$jquery-ui-tab)

Comment: @PawełFus the link you post is missed, but that's an idea, I'll give a try to set the width on execution. Thanks!

Comment: Proper link: http://docs.highcharts.com/#faq$jquery-ui-tab